# ASP.NET FormsAuthentication does not use default MembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, membership-provider

I have created a BasicMembershipProvider class that inherits from MembershipProvider, when implemented, the ValidateUser does not get called. This is my setup:

web.config

```
<membership defaultProvider="BasicMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="BasicMembershipProvider" type="MyMVCProject.Providers.BasicMembershipProvider"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```

BasicMembershipProvider.cs

```
public class BasicMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{       
  //THIS FUNCTION NEVER GETS CALLED
  public override bool ValidateUser(string email, string password)
  {
       //Do custom checks.
  }
}
```

Controller

```
FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(model.Email, model.Password)
```

Is this the way to go about overriding the MembershipProvider with my own membership logic? If so, why doesn't the overidden function `ValidateUser` gets called whenever I call `FormsAuthentication.Authenticate()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK the `FormsAuthentication.Authenticate` does not use `Membership.Validate` method. You have to call the `Membership.Validate` manually.

[**From MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.authenticate.aspx)

> The Authenticate method verifies user credentials that are stored in the credentials section of the application configuration file. Alternatively, you can use ASP.NET membership to store user credentials and call the ValidateUser to verify the credentials.

Comment: +1 Indeed. It does not, which is absolutely ridiculous. Like the rest of FormsAuthentication.

Comment: @Aliostad I LOL'd at the part about `FormsAuthentication` being ridiculous. Then I remember that it is, in fact, awful.  And that I'm stuck using it :(